# libxml install error using pip

Tags: python, lxml, pip

This is my error:

```
(mysite)zjm1126@zjm1126-G41MT-S2:~/zjm_test/mysite$ pip install lxml
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    Building lxml version 2.3.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: not found

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Building lxml version 2.3.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: not found

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4: fatal error: Python.h: 没有那个文件或目录
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/lxml/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-jOhgvD-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/include/site/python2.6:
    Building lxml version 2.3.

Building without Cython.

ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: not found



** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **



Using build configuration of libxslt

running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4: fatal error: Python.h: 没有那个文件或目录

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/lxml/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-jOhgvD-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/zjm1126/.pip/pip.log
```

What can I do?

**updated:**

```
(mysite)zjm1126@zjm1126-G41MT-S2:~/zjm_test/mysite$ pip install lxml
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    Building lxml version 2.3.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Building lxml version 2.3.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4: fatal error: Python.h: 没有那个文件或目录
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/lxml/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-NJw2ws-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/include/site/python2.6:
    Building lxml version 2.3.

Building without Cython.

Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26

Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib

running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4: fatal error: Python.h: 没有那个文件或目录

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/lxml/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-NJw2ws-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/zjm1126/.pip/pip.log
```

the log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/pip run on Thu Mar  3 17:07:27 2011
Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mysql-python
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
    warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python
    Running command /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/mysql-python/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-XuVIux-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/include/site/python2.6
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX
    In file included from _mysql.c:29:
    pymemcompat.h:10: fatal error: Python.h: 没有那个文件或目录
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/mysql-python/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-XuVIux-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/include/site/python2.6:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6

copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6

creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb

creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX

In file included from _mysql.c:29:

pymemcompat.h:10: fatal error: Python.h: 没有那个文件或目录

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/mysql-python/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-XuVIux-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 130, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 228, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 1043, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 559, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 249, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
InstallationError: Command /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/build/mysql-python/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-XuVIux-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/zjm1126/zjm_test/mysite/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1
```

Comment: It turned out to be a memory issue. Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26762938/578989

Answer (score 535):

> ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

From the [lxml documentation](https://lxml.de/installation.html#requirements), assuming you are running a Debian-based distribution :

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

For Debian based systems, it should be enough to install the known build dependencies of `python-lxml` or `python3-lxml`, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep python3-lxml
```

Comment: please paste the contents of /home/zjm1126/.pip/pip.log

Comment: I notice that you are not running it as super user, try sudo pip install lxml

Comment: `Python.h` is missing, so install python2.6-dev too: `sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev`

Comment: sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev

Comment: In Red Hat-based systems, (Red Hat, Suse, CentOS), replace dev in package names by devel. Therefore, the correct ones are: python-devel, libxml2-devel, libxslt-devel.

Comment: I was just missing: sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev

Comment: I'am using windows 7 x64.How can I install libxml2 and libxslt1?

Comment: I also had to install zlib1g-dev on Debian Jessie

Comment: @Jabba comment helped to resolve the same error for odoo 13 on centos 8. `Python.h` is the villain. Thanks

Answer (score 115):

This worked for me:

```
yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel
```

Comment: I confirm this on Fedora 18.

Comment: also Cent OS 6.4, with python-2.7

Comment: confirmed in Fedora 19 for pip install lxml --upgrade

Comment: confirmed for rhel 6 python 2.7

Comment: Works on Cygwin/Babun (use `pact install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel` for Babun).

Comment: I've done this but I've got `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4` on a Centos 7 server with python 3.4 virtual environment. Do you have any clues? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825789/install-lxml-on-centos-7-error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-4

Comment: Works on centOS 7.1 with python-2.7.6

Comment: Confirmed for Fedora 23 (though I used dnf instead of yum, lolz)

Comment: for debian: `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev`

Comment: rhel installation confirmed

Answer (score 80):

In case, you are using Ubuntu/Lubuntu 13.04 or Ubuntu 13.10 and having problem with "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz", you may need also install zlib1g-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
```

Put it all together:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python3-pip
sudo pip3 install lxml
```

Comment: I had to install this package for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as well.

Comment: This is the only answer in this thread the worked me, for Ubuntu 14.04LTS, 2 years later :) Thanks.

Comment: Yep, `zlib1g-dev` was the missing lib for me as well, on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I didn't need to run pip3. The first line did the trick for Ubuntu 16 server. Thanks.

Comment: After trying a thousand different packages, it looks like my problem was I was trying to install with `pip` and not `pip3` in the `python-slim` Docker container...

Comment: Works on Debian 10 as well.

Answer (score 35):

No you are missing the Python header files. This mostly happens on Linux when you are using the system Python (there are [reasons not to do that](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/), but that's a different question).

You probably need to install some package, and it's probably called python-dev or python-devel.

```
 sudo yum install python-devel
```

or

```
 sudo aptitude install python-dev
```

Or somesuch.

Comment: And why the downvote? This is the correct answer. It says "Python.h 没有那个文件或目录" Which means "no such file or directory". The python header files are missing. Install them and it will work.

Comment: The answer is correct. In my case, I had to install `python2.6-dev`.

Comment: This was my problem as well, except for the fact that I needed `python3-dev` to work on python3

Answer (score 25):

just install requirements:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

Now, you can install it with pip package management tool:

```
pip install lxml
```

For python3 users:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python3-dev

pip3 install lxml
```

Answer (score 12):

**On Windows**  I had the same error on windows when trying to manually install in Python 3.4 after it had been installed on 3.3.  I finally was able to solve it by installing the wheel and running pip from the Python34 directory.

1) download wheel from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

2) `cd Python34\Scripts`

3) `pip.exe C:\Users\Home\Downloads\lxml- ......... .whl`

Comment: For Python 3.5 seems you need the 'install' command:

`pip.exe install C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: ERROR: lxml-4.4.1-pp372-pp372-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.  I'm running windows 10. I get the same error trying to install the amd64 version.

Answer (score 10):

I solved this issue by increasing my server ram.

I was running only 512 MB and when I upgraded to 1 GB I had no problem.

I also installed every package manually prior to this in an attempt to fix the problem, but I'm not sure whether this is a necessary step.

Comment: I helped, but in a different case. Here the gcc exit status 1. In my case it was 4 (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149613/installing-lxml-with-pip-in-virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10-error-command-gcc-failed

Comment: this fixed it for me, was using boo2docker so increased vm RAM. thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I had this problem in a vagrant VM and it solved it.

Comment: This is the kind of answer that teaches you to scroll past the accepted answer. This was a huge time saver.

Comment: yes, this is the issue for people who use virtualization (Vagrant). thank you this solved my problem

Answer (score 7):

```
STATIC_DEPS=true easy_install lxml
```

Answer (score 6):

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

yum remove audit
yum install gcc
yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel

cd lxml-x.x.x
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and this solves the issue for me

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-lxml
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. More specifically 'apt-get install python-lxml'

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

and then try upgrading python setuptools

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

this should resolve it.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me also for  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 .

Answer (score 4):

Installing a lxml binary would do the trick. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904752/install-libxml2-and-associated-python-bindings-windows/1904784#1904784)

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue with a pip install of lxml. My CentOS instance was using python 2.6 which was throwing this error.

To get around this I did the following to run with Python 2.7:

1. Run: `sudo yum install python-devel`
2. Run `sudo yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel`
3. Use Python 2.7 to run your command by using `/usr/bin/python2.7 YOUR_PYTHON_COMMAND`
   (For me it was `/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install lxml`)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error on my Linux machine.If you go to their [website](http://lxml.de/installation.html) that's in their documentation as well.So if you get this kind of error in **Linux machine**, please try out these commands,

`# apt install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev`

`# pip install lxml==3.4.4`

Answer (score 2):

`pymemcompat.h:10: fatal error: Python.h: 没有那个文件或目录`

Boy you should post your error log with `LANG=C` or people can't get the real cause from your log. The log above says: No such file or directory.

That means you should install the develop package of Python. That's usually "python-dev" on Debian flavored distro, and "python-devel" on RHEL flavored distro.

Comment: You're replying to a 3 year old question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

All the answers above assume the user has access to a privileged/root account to install the required libraries. To install it locally you will need to do the following steps. Only showed the overview since the steps can get a little involved depending on the dependencies that you might be missing

1.Download and Compile libxml2-2.9.1 & libxslt-1.1.28(versions might change)

2.Configure each install path for both libxml and libxslt to be some local directory using configure. Ex. `./configure --prefix=/home_dir/dependencies/libxslt_path`

3.Run `make` then `make install`

4.Download and compile lxml from source

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, 12.04, python2.7.6

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
sudo pip install lxml
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to the show,

But this will help if nothing else works out

```
mkdir ~/tmp
export TMPDIR=~/tmp
STATIC_DEPS=true easy_install-2.7 lxml
```

Setting TMPDIR will ensure that the build can run everything that it needs to run, and setting STATIC_DEPS will tell it to pull in its own libxml2 and 
libxslt2, instead of using the old versions installed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Using cygwin 64 with Windows 8.

I have got...

> pip install lxml
>       (...)

```
gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.2.5-4.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.2.5-4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.2.5-4.x86_64/src/Python-3.2.5=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.2.5-4 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-b8ybku/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.2m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.cygwin-1.7.34-x86_64-3.2/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py:257: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.2m -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-b8ybku/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-u3vwj8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-b8ybku/lxml
```

I have tried everything until I realized a new cygwin toolchain has messed up python logic. cygwin install a compiler called "realgcc" that is not a *real* gcc.

Solution

Install gcc. Ex:

```
 apt-cyg install gcc-g++
```

Comment: Nice.. it worked for me.. only difference is i am on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

The only thing helped for me was

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 12, and this works for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install lxml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the libxml2 and libxslt, maybe you need to create a symbolic link between libxml2 and libxslt path to python2.6 include path. Also you can try to add INCLUDE environment argument.
Because the gcc command only search this path: -I/usr/include/python2.6.

Answer (score 0):

The below file worked for me on windows 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.3#downloads

Answer (score 0):

On osx 10.10.5 and in a virtualenv, maybe you can resolve that problem like below:

```
sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include pip install -r lxml
```

Comment: That may be helpful in former releases of osx.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 7 with Cygwin, I came across:

```
Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitZsgdMQ.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitZsgdMQ.o
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I fixed it by installing `mingw64-x86_64-libxslt`

Comment: Hi, I think I may be abit out of my league here but how/where exactly do you install that file

Answer (score 0):

I work on a Windows machine. And here are some pointers for successful installation of lxml (with python 2.6 and later).

Have the following installed:

1. MingGW.
2. libxml2 version 2.7.0 or later.
3. libxslt version 1.1.23 or later.

All are not available at a `pip install`.

libxml2's windows binary is found [here](https://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html).

libxslt is found [here](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/).

After you are done with the above two,

do : `pip install lxml`.

Another workaround is using the stable releases from PyPI or the unofficial Windows binaries by Christoph Gohlke ([found here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)).

Answer (score 0):

These two packages need to be installed separately and usually can't be installed using `pip`...Therefore, for FreeBSD:

```
Download a compressed snapshot of the Ports Collection into /var/db/portsnap:
# portsnap fetch
When running Portsnap for the first time, extract the snapshot into /usr/ports:
# portsnap extract
After the first use of Portsnap has been completed as shown above, /usr/ports can be updated as needed by running:
# portsnap fetch
# portsnap update

Now Install:
cd /usr/ports/textproc/libxml2
make install clean

cd /usr/ports/textproc/libxslt
make install clean
```

You should be good to go...

Answer (score -2):

For Windows:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel
pip install bzt
pip install lxml
```