# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXMLParser

Tags: linux, centos7

I'm trying to install an application and I get the following error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXMLParser
I couldn't find anything about lXMLParser anywhere. Where does this come from?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Looks like you miss libxml2/libxml2-dev. Or root-io-xml. It depends what you try to build. Could you please provide more info

Comment: [How do I find package with Yum?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85715/56041) and [Searching for packages using apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111377/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Also see [How to install lxml on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6504810/608639) and [Can't install lxml on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20886069/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help. I was trying to install a package which seems it was using ROOT.
So what one has to do enable xml when configuring ROOT; i.e:
./configure --enable-xml.