# setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, pip, odoo

When I try to install `odoo-server`, I got the following error:

```
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Sometimes it's the line above this error you should look at. It should tell you what package is missing.

Comment: The most frustrating thing is that it hides the actual error message.

Comment: If you have received this error message while trying to install Odoo, [Kenly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35164888/5320906) is the most applicable.  Otherwise, consider for a Q&A more specific to the package that you are trying to install, and the object that GCC is unable to locate.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Try installing these packages.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-pil python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev libssl-dev

sudo easy_install greenlet

sudo easy_install gevent
```

Comment: i didn't found any reasonable answer about why this error happen! why we need to install all these packages...if possible then kindly explain "'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed" to me

Comment: Yeah, one of these packages might fix it but it would be nice to know which one particularly

Comment: build-essential and python-dev were enough in my case.

Comment: Downvoted for not answering the question. Why do I have to install qt4-docs to fix this problem?

Comment: build-essential and python-dev is enough for my

Comment: should i use python3- for all packages if i want to run on python 3.5.1?

Comment: The only ones that are necessary are actually build-essential and python-dev

Comment: Just installing this packages on ubuntu 14.4 did the trick for me:
>sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl  python-pyre

Though this installed "python-dev" as dependency as next solution claims though it might be enough just this package

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-dev` solves the problem

Comment: I had tried with `build-essential` and `python-dev` but it did not work then finally I just copied full line 
`sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev` And It worked like a charm :D

Comment: @ShaneReustle The very last one, actually. Hah

Comment: Answer does not give a definitive answer to the question, just asks the user to install a bunch of packages in 'hopes' that one of them fixes your problem.

Comment: in ubuntu you only need build-essential and python-dev, in linux mint only python-dev

Comment: libssl-dev did it for me

Comment: For ubuntu server 20.04, build-essential and python-dev did the job.

Comment: You only need `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and `sudo apt-get install python3.*-dev`

Comment: build-essential solved the problem for me.

Comment: It might resolve the problem, no doubts about that, but I believe this is certainly not the "minimum" number of packages that achieve the same result. For example, installing `python3-dev` and `gcc` was enough in my case.

Comment: @Shashank same as me i am using ubuntu 20.04 and Pycharm. i dont know why i need to install python3.x-dev to my source where it is already bulitin on pycharm env.

Comment: It is a lot of packages, but everyone's needs will be different. This answer is to ensure you have no issues. It's best too install and test each package, one by one, if your are concerned about too many packages

Comment: For me, adding the additional package including the mentioned as worked like a charm.


"RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip libffi-dev libssl-dev cargo \
&& pip3 install typing_extensions pdfminer.six"


We're using Docker for one of our services.

Answer (score 621):

I encountered the same problem in college having installed *Linux Mint* for the main project of my final year, the third solution below worked for me.

When encountering this error please note before the error it may say you are ***missing*** a package or header file — you should find those and install them and verify if it works (e.g. ssl → libssl).

For **Python 2.x** use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For **Python 2.7** use:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

For **Python 3.x** use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

or for a specific version of Python 3, replace *`x`* with the minor version in

```
sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev
```

Comment: I have a comment here for python 2 (2.7) that works with sudo apt-get install libffi-dev , I will agree with python3-dev for py34 solution that worked for me.

Comment: Helped for python 3

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev solved for me . because i updated to 3.6

Comment: Solution for Python 2.7 WORKED for Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. Perfect!

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Schütze, but this isn't the accepted answer for the question, I'm always happy to help, so you can tell me about your error or you can try the accepted or other solutions, or raise a question on Stackoverflow to solve your problem.

Comment: I use additionally **apt-get install build-essential** to solve my problem.

Comment: Helped for python 3.7

Comment: i would add that in ubuntu you also have to install build-essential. i've just solved this issue with it. in linux mint i had the same problem and python-dev solved it alone.

Comment: @Paulie how to install in a virtualenv? I've python 3.6 in venv and globally python3.6, it is installed for global python3.6 but can't install for python3.6. Any work around?

Comment: @FurqanHashim My solution isn't to fix odoo-server, it's a fix for the actual error.

Comment: just for adding more info, this error solved for me by answers from this QA -> [https://stackoverflow.com/q/34819221/4417806]

Comment: needed `apt-get install python3.x-dev` for python 3.7

Comment: ```$ sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev``` worked for `python3.7`

Comment: Thanks.....this works for me ....for specific python version

Comment: I had already installed ``python3.x-dev`` but still had problems, but Samuel's suggestion of ``sudo apt-get install build-essential`` worked perfectly

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev` works like a charm :)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev` works perfectly on my Linux board. The other commands cannot. Thank you~

Comment: @SamuelDauzon's suggestion works like charm

Comment: Thank you! This was the only solution that helped for Python3.8.14.

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential worked for me

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3.11-dev worked for me

Comment: I don't know why `apt install build-essential python-dev` doesn't help but I have to use `apt install python3.8-dev`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python2-dev` worked for python 2.7 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 292):

> Python.h is nothing but a header file. It is used by gcc to build applications. You need to install a package called python-dev. This package includes header files, a static library and development tools for building Python modules, extending the Python interpreter or embedding Python in applications.

enter:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

**or**

```
# apt-get install python-dev
```

see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-python-h-file-not-found-error-solution/

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me: `Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version.`

Comment: @SummerSun If you're using python3, you should use: $sudo apt-get install python3-dev or $ sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev

Comment: @antoinet but i am using python 2.7.4... I have solved this long ago but i don't remember any specific solution

Comment: Definitely worked for me: Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit; zshell + tmux

Comment: The installation of "python-dev" helped me. I'm installing yara through pip install. Thank you!

Comment: For python3.x use the command $sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev

Comment: if you are using ubuntu, you also need to install build-essential. check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54534118/3453776

Comment: Mentioning python version is important, in my case this command installed `python-dev` for python 2.7 which didn't work. But when I mentioned the version like: `sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev` this worked (I also had python 3.8 installed in my machine). See @kame's answer.

Comment: worked for me. I install a specific old Python version (3.7) and needed to install further dependencies

Comment: I need to add my python version because I use virtual environment `sudo apt-get install python3.11-dev`

Answer (score 145):

You need to install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: This one worked for me. I had all python and build packages from previous answers, **I was missing these lib* packages**. THANKS!

Comment: Worked on void linux.

Comment: This will most likely work on clean systems, but in my case all I was missing was the 3 packages: `libldap2-dev`, `libpq-dev` and `libsasl2-dev`

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 19.10 with Python 3.7

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 2.7

Comment: Thank you it worked for 20.04 with python 3.8

Comment: This worked for me. Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.9.6.

Comment: I only needed to install `libpq-dev` in my case (Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8). Encountered the error while trying to `pip install psycopg2`.

Comment: this saved my life on a containerization of an app for arm64, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 90):

For **Python 3.5** use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

For **Python 3.6** use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

For **Python 3.7** use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

For **Python 3.8** use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

... and so on ...

Comment: As a side note, I just used sudo `apt-get install python3.6-dev` and it also worked.

Comment: Boy that was tough -- I installed everything mentioned above on my system until this one finally fixed it for me. I'm using a virtualenv with python3.6. Thank you for that.

Comment: Perfect!! Solved!

Comment: I'm using the Python3.8 `sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev`

Comment: With every new version of python I land here again :-)

Comment: So clean that is it not even reasonable! Thanks!

Answer (score 74):

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
$ sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-docutils python-feedparser python-gdata python-jinja2 python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-mock python-openid python-psycopg2 python-psutil python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-unittest2 python-vatnumber python-vobject python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi
```

OR TRY THIS:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

Answer (score 39):

In my case, it was missing package **libffi-dev**.

What worked:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 39):

For me none of above worked. However, I solved problem with installing `libssl-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

This might work if you have same error message as in my case:

> fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory ... ....
>   command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Me too. The accepted answer seems a little excessive.

Comment: This worked for me as well without having to download a bunch from the accepted answer

Comment: This is usually this library that is missing when I install cryptography package in python.

Comment: This was the issue for me too. I could tell it from the stdout line "src/pycurl.h:164:28: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory" printed just before the line questioned in this post "error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Answer (score 29):

In my case following command did the magic

```
sudo apt-get install gcc python3-dev
```

if the above command didn't work try following two commands

```
sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev
```

1. this is the case when you want it to install for the python version set as default python in your machine.

Or

```
sudo apt-get install gcc python3.x-dev
```

2. where `python3.x` represent the `version` number of python installed on your machine.

Comment: python3.7-dev package helped me. All the others not really. Only after I installed this one it worked.

Comment: i love u it was gcc for me and python3-dev :)

Answer (score 17):

on ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-file search ffi.h
```

returned:

```
chipmunk-dev: /usr/include/chipmunk/chipmunk_ffi.h
ghc-doc: /usr/share/doc/ghc-doc/html/users_guide/ffi.html
jython-doc: /usr/share/doc/jython-doc/html/javadoc/org/python/modules/jffi/jffi.html
libffi-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ffi.h
libffi-dev: /usr/share/doc/libffi6/html/Using-libffi.html
libgirepository1.0-dev: /usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0/girffi.h
libgirepository1.0-doc: /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gi/gi-girffi.html
mlton-basis: /usr/lib/mlton/include/basis-ffi.h
pypy-doc: /usr/share/doc/pypy-doc/html/config/objspace.usemodules._ffi.html
pypy-doc: /usr/share/doc/pypy-doc/html/config/objspace.usemodules._rawffi.html
pypy-doc: /usr/share/doc/pypy-doc/html/rffi.html
```

I chose to install libffi-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

worked perfectly

Comment: Not only this solution helped me fix my `ffi.h` missing dependency but also helped fixing other missing dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: This really helped. I was missing file called ```pcrecpp.h```. And the package I had to install was ```libpcre3-dev```.

Answer (score 17):

In my case `pip` was unable to install libraries, I tried solutions given above, but none worked but the below worked for me:

```
sudo apt upgrade gcc
```

Comment: Usually this Happens when we dont use environment

Answer (score 11):

Despite being an old question, I'll add my opinion.

I think the right answer depends on the error message of the gcc compiler, something like "Missing xxxx.h"

This might help in some cases:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

Answer (score 9):

This was enough for me:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 6):

In Linux Mint with python3

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential python3-dev
```

should be enough

Answer (score 5):

below answer worked for me, you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-lxml
```

Comment: And for python2:`sudo apt-get install python-lxml`

Answer (score 5):

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a `virtualenv` running python 3.5, I had to do:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

The other commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Did not help. I think this is because the `virtualenv` needs to rely on the system-wide `python-dev` package and it must match the `virtualenv`'s python version. However, using the above commands installs `python-dev` for python 2.x and the python 3.x that comes with Ubuntu 14.04 which is 3.4, not 3.5.

Answer (score 5):

> Error : error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Executing `sudo apt-get install python-dev` solved the error.

Comment: Or executing `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`.

Answer (score 4):

After upgrade my computer with pip today, and check the other answers here, I can tell you that it could be ANYTHING. You should check error by error, looking for what's the specific library that you need. In my case, these were the libraries that I had to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libvirt-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

HTH

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, 12.04, python2.7.6

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
sudo apt-get install lxml
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package lxml`  I get the following. :(

Comment: @kRazzyR try to run `sudo apt-get install python-lxml` command

Answer (score 4):

first you need to find out what the actual problem was. what you're seeing is that the C compiler failed but you don't yet know why. scroll up to where you get the original error. in my case, trying to install some packages using `pip3`, I found:

```
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4u59c_8b/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-itjeh3va-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory

 #include <ffi.h>

                 ^

compilation terminated.
```

so in my case I needed to install `libffi-dev`.

Comment: For sure, this compiler error presented on the question, is very relative. My case, for example, was just like yours: I was installing `bcrypt` via `pip3`, and the output was quite huge and observing the first messages from `pip3 install bcrypt`, I realized that `libffi-dev` was the package which was causing all the trouble for the next steps of the installation process. Well observed, friend :). I hope you don't my mind, if I give some cents to your answer, which for me, deserves a better consideration. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the command `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev` resolved the issue. I was getting an error specific to the sql.h header file.

Comment: This was the same issue I was facing i.e. "an error specific to the sql.h header file" and this solution worked!

Comment: Yes i had the same issue , this worked fine for me

Comment: Yep that was the only thing I needed too!

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev

sudo easy_install greenlet

sudo easy_install gevent
```

Answer (score 3):

*Tip*: Please do not consider this as an answer. Just to help someone else too.

I had similar issue while installing **psycopg2**. I installed`build-essential`, `python-dev` and also `libpq-dev` but it thrown same error.

```
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

As I was in hurry in deployment so finally just copied full line from
@user3440631's answer.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev
```

And It worked like a charm. but could not find which package has resolved my issue. 
Please update the comment if anyone have idea about `psycopg2` dependancy package from above command.

Comment: I have solved my **psycopg2** problem by installing **postgresql-devel** package on CentOS.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Lot of time I got the same error when installing `M2Crypto` & `pygraphviz` and installed all the things mention in the [approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26333011/6194097). But this below line solved all my problems with the other packages in [approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26333011/6194097) too.

```sh
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev swig
sudo apt-get install -y graphviz-dev
```

This [`swig`](http://www.swig.org/svn.html) package saved my life as the solution for `M2Crypto` and [`graphviz-dev`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/) for `pygraphviz`. I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to make sure I was using the correct version of cryptography.
pip.freeze had and older version and once I used the latest the problem when away.

Answer (score 2):

For Centos 7 Use below command to install Python Development Package

***Python 2.7***

> sudo yum install python-dev

***Python 3.4***

> sudo yum install python34-devel

Still if your problem not solved then try installing below packages -

> sudo yum install libffi-devel
>
> sudo yum install openssl-devel

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me when I had the same issue on my Ubuntu 14.04

However, this solved the error:

`sudo apt-get install python-numpy libicu-dev`

Comment: `Odoo` don't depend on `python-numpy`.

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to install `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt1-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

My stack was like that:

```
> >                            ^
> >     In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:156:0,
> >                      from OpenSSL/crypto/x509.h:17,
> >                      from OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.h:17,
> >                      from OpenSSL/crypto/crl.c:3:
> >     /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:751:15: note: previous declaration of ‘X509_REVOKED_dup’ was here
> >      X509_REVOKED *X509_REVOKED_dup(X509_REVOKED *rev);
> >                    ^
> >     error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
> >     
> >     ----------------------------------------   Rolling back uninstall of > pyOpenSSL Command "/home/marta/env/pb/bin/python -u -c
> "import setuptools,
> > tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-14ekWY/pyOpenSSL/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
> > '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
> > --record /tmp/pip-2HERvW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/marta/env/pb/include/site/python2.7/pyOpenSSL" failed with error
> > code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-14ekWY/pyOpenSSL/
```

in the same case, please consider the typo (bug) in one of the installation files and edit it manually by changing "X509_REVOKED_dup" to "X509_REVOKED_dupe" (no quotes). I have edited the x509.h file:

> sed -e's/X509_REVOKED_dup/X509_REVOKED_dupe/g' -i
>   usr/include/openssl/x509.h

and it worked for me, but please consult with the post linked below, as they edited another file:

> sed -e's/X509_REVOKED_dup/X509_REVOKED_dupe/g' -i OpenSSL/crypto/crl.c

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/Qt0jNIOACZc

Answer (score 1):

Like [Robin Winslow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613540/robin-winslow) says in a comment :

> I found my solution over here: [stackoverflow.com/a/5178444/613540](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178444/613540)

In my case, my complete error message was :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I was trying to install [torrench](https://github.com/kryptxy/torrench) :

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

With given stackoverflow link, I solve this issue by :

```
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev
```

Note that the following packages were already installed :

```
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
python3-dev is already the newest version.
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
```

Hope that will help !

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was `oursql` that was causing the same(generic) error as below.

```
In file included from oursqlx/oursql.c:236:0:
  oursqlx/compat.h:13:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for oursql
  Running setup.py clean for oursql
```

So, I knew that I need to have `libmysqlcppconn-dev` package.

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

And all good!

Comment: On the general note, I later checked the setup.py file of oursql package and found out that it uses mysqld and thus I installed `sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev` and it worked for me.

Comment: macOS solution for oursql installation problems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/663919/how-do-i-install-oursql-using-pip/1086651#1086651

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: run the below command

```bash
sudo apt-get install python2-dev gcc
```

I had this problem when trying to pip install a module for `python2.7`.

Lots of answers mention that a fix for this is `sudo apt-get install python-dev`. However, this did not work for me, as the package was not found. However, the command shown at the top of this comment exists, and I was finally able to pip install the module.

Answer (score 1):

For python3:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-dev \
     build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
     libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
     python3-pip
```

For Python2:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python2-dev  \
     build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
     libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
     python2-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me:

sudo apt install zlib1g-dev

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some other helpful answers, if docker-compose brought you here--With your venv set, run:

```
easy_install docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

While installing ssdeep i was getting same error Please check actual error can be something else Like i was also getting same but above this error there was an error fuzzy.h no file or directory and then i tried this
`apt-get -y install libfuzzy-dev`

Work like charm

Answer (score 0):

This problem can originate from one of any missing packages especially in newer builds.

```
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/home/vipin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/bbox-drf-QjIedbEI-py3.9/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/base64.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/base64.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/home/vipin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/bbox-drf-QjIedbEI-py3.9/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/kerberos.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/kerberos.o
    In file included from src/kerberos.c:20:
    src/kerberosbasic.h:17:10: fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory
       17 | #include <gssapi/gssapi.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
    [end of output]
```

most of us search using the second last line.

> error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

But if you look closely, a few lines above, you can actually see which package is missing. It clearly states that a directory or file is missing

> gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory

searching why this package could be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

After installing a lot of libraries, the one that worked for me! was `swig`:

```
sudo apt-get install swig
```

The error arose when installing python's `M2Crypto` library.

:)