# sudo pip install python-Levenshtein failed with error code 1

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to install the python-Levenshtein library on linux, but whenever I try to install it via:

```
sudo pip install python-Levenshtein
```

I get this error:

> Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-LAmG4b/python-Levenshtein/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KGiQPH-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-LAmG4b/python-Levenshtein

And the error code: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I'm using debian linux.

Comment: Most likely, you don't have `gcc` or the build tools installed. Verify this by typing `which gcc` in your terminal. Can you try again after executing `sudo apt-get install build-essential`?

Comment: @birryree my build-essential is the latest version and gcc gives me /usr/bin/gcc also latest when i tried to upgrade it.

Comment: Hm, in that case, before you resort to more serious debugging methods - do you have `libpython-dev` installed? That package is also needed to build a lot of Python modules that bind with C or expose C extensions.

Comment: @birryree thank you! i just installed python-dev, for some reason it was not installed. please submit an answer so i can accept it!

Comment: Have you tried reading /tmp/pip-build-LAmG4b/python-Levenshtein to see what the error is?  This might well point at libpython-dev being missing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One of the `python-Levenshtein` maintainers here.

Make sure you have `python-dev` and `build-essential` packages.

Are you sure that's full error message as the actual error seem to be missing?

If a log file is created can you peek into it and add its content to the question.

Also read the official Python package installation guide. [Use virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing/#creating-virtual-environments). Never do `sudo pip install` unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Comment: You brought me on the right track - I was missing `libpython3-dev`. Modern times...

Comment: Could you add some more guidance on how to install both? I believe python-dev can be installed in macOS by brew reinstall python3.x, but how can I install build-essential?

Comment: These instructions apply to Ubuntu Linux from 2015. if you have an issue please open a new question and describe your setup and problem in detail.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case if anyone will encounter the same issue as the author of this question:

I faced the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04. I wanted to use a library which depends on python-Levenstein.

[Mikkos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315168/mikko-ohtamaa) answer above was correct. When installing, I have obtained further line in the end of exception:
`'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`
which directly means a problem with building tool.

Then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874511/4658703) by [Paulie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2467327/paulie)

Overall, in my case it was simply executing:
`sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev`

Then I installed the library using:

`pip install python-Levenshtein`

I hope this will be clear for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when installing python-Levenshtein and I was able to install it like this:

```
pip install conda
```

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-levenshtein
```