# error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' when installing mysqlclient

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.4

I installed django 1.8.5 in virtualenv and using python 3.4.3
the worked displayed the **it works** page when using sqlite

I wanted to use mysql and I'm trying to install mysqlclient using

`pip install mysqlclient`

and I'm getting the following message

```
----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient
Complete output from command /home/sasidhar/django/env/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5lj39q67/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-da2_35zs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sasidhar/django/env/include/site/python3.4/mysqlclient:
running install
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,6,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sasidhar/django/env/include/python3.4m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -DNDEBUG
_mysql.c:40:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/sasidhar/django/env/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5lj39q67/mysqlclient/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-da2_35zs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sasidhar/django/env/include/site/python3.4/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5lj39q67/mysqlclient
```

I did try installing libraries suggested in [error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit)

and still the problem persists
please help me solve this problem
Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to install python-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

And, since you are using python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

This command should help you.

If you are using mac os you might try:

```
brew update && brew rm python3 && brew install python3
```

You need to brew has been installed already, otherwise you can install it. It is very useful for getting packages in Mac OS. http://brew.sh/

Comment: @sasidhar yep, you can use 'sudo apt-get install python3-dev'

Comment: thank you very much sir I almost tried it for 6 hrs yesterday
I also installed python-dev but 
`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`  
did the trick

Comment: Thank you once again sir  
you made my day :)
now running django with mysql db :))

Comment: @sasidhar no problem. :) Good luck. :)

Answer (score 33):

For Ubuntu you also need to install build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: this should be added to the main answer. it might be ubuntu specific (i don't know but i didn't need to install this on linux mint to solve the same problem) but it will help many people with this issue for sure.

Comment: I don't know if it needs to be answered to the main answer or not but it was definitely necessary in my case (Ubuntu 18.04)  - +1

Comment: this really helps me, have tried installing python3-dev and other dependencies but then found the issues from this one

Comment: this was the step that got it finally working for me (on ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 11):

For those using different versions, such as Python 3.5, 3.6 or 3.7 I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874511/120296):

## Part I

For **Python 2.x** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For **Python 2.7** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

For **Python 3.x** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

For **Python 3.4** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
```

For **Python 3.7** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

## Part II

If this still doesn't help, [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54382328/120296) have pointed out to install

```
  $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and finally

```
  $ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

But the last two didn't help me personally. Just in case, hope it helps you.

Comment: Last two helped. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

For those using python3.5:

```
apt-get install python3.5-dev
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.5 get-pip.py
pip3.5 install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of the above suggestions and a few found elsewhere and nothing worked. In the end the solution was simple enough (courtesy of ignacionf on GitHub):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python.git
```