# Error installing mysqlclient for python on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, pip, mysql-python

I installed Python 2.7.15rci and Python 3.6.7 on Ubuntu. When i did 'pip list' on virtualenv it returns me:

```
Django (2.1.5)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
pytz (2018.9)
setuptools (39.0.1)
wheel (0.32.3)
```

I'm trying to install mysqlclient (pip install mysqlclient) and returns an error.

```
  unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /home/david/env/project/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pq18uxjj/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-y28h4ou0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/david/env/project/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient:
    /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,1,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/david/env/project/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/david/env/project/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pq18uxjj/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-y28h4ou0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/david/env/project/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pq18uxjj/mysqlclient/
```

So, I have tried different methods found like:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and some more... but none of them work for me and the problem persists. 
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: you need to install `default-libmysqlclient-dev` according to the docs, not `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Comment: I installed `default-libmysqlclient-dev` too but it still does not work ...

Comment: You say you've tried `sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev`, are those still installed? Or did you uninstall each time? All of these need to be installed.

Comment: Yes, they are still installed
python-dev (2.7.15~rc1-1)
python3-dev (3.6.7-1~18.04)
default-libmysqlclient-dev (1.0.4)
libmysqlclient-dev (8.0.14-1ubuntu18.04)

Comment: you're using python3, so only one that matters is python3-dev. Try also installing `gcc` (`sudo apt-get install gcc`).

Comment: the problem persists :(

Comment: exact same error?

Comment: no, now it does not put "unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory" at the end and put 
    
`/usr/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lssl`
`/usr/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lcrypto`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Check which version of python3-dev is installed: `dpkg -s python3-dev` it's strange you're missing so many libraries. It could be that you should install `python3.6-dev` instead. If it's 3.6, then try installing `libssl-dev`. And continue for each error you get.

Comment: this is strange, i just installed it without any issue on Ubuntu 18.0.4 with the default python (3.6). Exactly by installing `python3-dev gcc default-libmysqlclient-dev`. Those were enough.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't have those libraries installed but I installed `libssl-dev` and it worked! Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`gcc` is part of the `build-essential` package, which you should install before anything else:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

**UPDATE:** Following @bosnjak's suggestion, you also might need to install the openssl developer tools:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: Even after installing all of the above, it didn't work for me in Ubuntu 18.04, until I did `sudo apt install libssl-dev`, which fixed the issue.

Comment: @bosnjak solution worked thanks !! I was trying to install on fresh ubuntu 18.04 installation

Comment: @bosnjak Yes! That's exactly what the problem was. The traceback states `cannot find -lssl`, so you really need to install `libssl-dev` to build mysqlclient on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 22):

I specified the particular version of python it's 3.7
And that helped me

I have installed these ones:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

And then installed mysqlclient by:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: this helped me again :)

Comment: Nestor, I was glad to help you! 
It helps me sometimes as well :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed my issue. you saved my a lot of time :)

Answer (score 10):

I turned out, that the solution is slightly different for almost every Python version. For those using different versions, such as Python 2.x, 3.5 or 3.7 I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874511/120296):

## Part I

For **Python 2.x** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

For **Python 2.7** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

For **Python 3.x** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

For **Python 3.4** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
```

For **Python 3.7** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

For **Python 3.8** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

For **Python 3.9** use:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev
```

## Part II

If this still doesn't help, [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54382328/120296) have pointed out to install

```
  $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and finally

```
  $ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

But the last two didn't help myself - but hoping this might help you!

Comment: this fixed it for me on python3.8 and ubuntu 22.04

Comment: The last one helped me! Using python 3.8.15. Ubunt 22. Thanks!

Comment: Adding libssl-dev as suggested in part II was the step that fixed it for me, Linux Mint 21, Python 3.10.12 (also using repo.mysql.com in apt settings, not sure if that's relevant)

Answer (score 2):

This issue was persistent in Ubuntu and python 3+. In my case, I was using Ubuntu 18.04 and found this solution to be useful for python version 3.7.5

Step 1. Install libpython3.7-dev via sudo apt

```
> sudo apt-get install libpython3.7-dev
```

Step 2: Install mysqlclient

```
> python3 -m pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed my issue. you saved my a lot time.

Answer (score 2):

You may do this before:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

Source: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Comment: particularly `default-libmysqlclient-dev` has helped.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to install the 'Modoboa' mail-server package (https://github.com/modoboa/modoboa) on my Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache as my webserver, instead of nginx. I needed `mysqlclient` for Python 2.7. The following packages worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev gcc python2.7-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the python3.8. Similarly to david's answer, use the following command then it works.

$ sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7, MariaDB 10.1, Python 3.11, latest possible version - 2.1.1:

```
pip install mysqlclient==2.1.1
```

If you try to install a later version, you will get an error:

> × Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run
> successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> [51 lines of output]
>
> ...
>
> src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c:539:49: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_SSL_ENFORCE’ undeclared
> (first use in this function)
> mysql_optionsv(&(self->connection), MYSQL_OPT_SSL_ENFORCE, (void *)&enforce_tls);
>
> ...
>
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
>
> ...
>
> Failed to build mysqlclient ERROR: Could not build wheels for
> mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based
> projects