# Oursql install : error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, oursql

I've gone through most of the previous errors and installed already in a python 3.5 virtualenv:
python3-dev
libmysqlclient-dev
libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev
libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev-compat

But

> sudo pip install oursql

still get this error:

```
Installing collected packages: oursql
  Running setup.py install for oursql ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-

build-fHedbn/oursql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r

\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-V5ljoT-record/install-record.txt --single-

version-externally-managed --compile:
    cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file.
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'oursql' extension
    mysql_config --cflags
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/oursqlx
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing 

-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -

I/usr/include/python2.7 -c oursqlx/oursql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/oursqlx/oursql.o -

I/usr/include/mysql -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    In file included from /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:64:0,
                     from oursqlx/compat.h:13,
                     from oursqlx/oursql.c:235:
    /usr/include/mysql/mysql/client_plugin.h:97:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-

Wstrict-prototypes]
       MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
       ^
    In file included from /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:64:0,
                     from oursqlx/compat.h:13,
                     from oursqlx/oursql.c:235:
    /usr/include/mysql/mysql/client_plugin.h:107:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-

Wstrict-prototypes]
       MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
       ^
    oursqlx/oursql.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6oursql_6Cursor_4callproc’:
    oursqlx/oursql.c:16330:13: warning: variable ‘__pyx_v_params’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-

variable]
       PyObject *__pyx_v_params = 0;
                 ^
    oursqlx/oursql.c:16329:13: warning: variable ‘__pyx_v_procname’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-

variable]
       PyObject *__pyx_v_procname = 0;
                 ^
    oursqlx/oursql.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6oursql_6Cursor_14setoutputsize’:
    oursqlx/oursql.c:18140:13: warning: variable ‘__pyx_v_column’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-

variable]
       PyObject *__pyx_v_column = 0;
                 ^
    oursqlx/oursql.c:18139:13: warning: variable ‘__pyx_v_size’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-

variable]
       PyObject *__pyx_v_size = 0;
                 ^
    oursqlx/oursql.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6oursql_6Cursor_16__exit__’:
    oursqlx/oursql.c:18245:13: warning: variable ‘__pyx_v_tb’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       PyObject *__pyx_v_tb = 0;
                 ^
    oursqlx/oursql.c:18244:13: warning: variable ‘__pyx_v_value’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-

variable]
       PyObject *__pyx_v_value = 0;
                 ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing 

-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -

I/usr/include/python2.7 -c oursqlx/compat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/oursqlx/compat.o -

I/usr/include/mysql -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    In file included from /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:64:0,
                     from oursqlx/compat.h:13,
                     from oursqlx/compat.c:1:
    /usr/include/mysql/mysql/client_plugin.h:97:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-

Wstrict-prototypes]
       MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
       ^
    In file included from /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:64:0,
                     from oursqlx/compat.h:13,
                     from oursqlx/compat.c:1:
    /usr/include/mysql/mysql/client_plugin.h:107:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-

Wstrict-prototypes]
       MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
       ^
    In file included from oursqlx/compat.c:55:0:
    oursqlx/_exceptions.c: In function ‘_oursqlx_exc_from_errno’:
    oursqlx/_exceptions.c:620:24: error: ‘ER_ERROR_FIRST’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                 if (err >= ER_ERROR_FIRST && err <= ER_ERROR_LAST)
                            ^
    oursqlx/_exceptions.c:620:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function 

it appears in
    oursqlx/_exceptions.c:620:49: error: ‘ER_ERROR_LAST’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                 if (err >= ER_ERROR_FIRST && err <= ER_ERROR_LAST)
                                                     ^
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-

fHedbn/oursql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', 

'\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-V5ljoT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-

externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fHedbn/oursql/
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to an update to MySQL 5.7. Some constants were removed which breaks the `oursql` build. See this [pull request in oursql](https://github.com/python-oursql/oursql/pull/4).

An upgrade to `oursql >= 0.9.3.2` should fix this issue.

Be aware that this `0.9.3.2` fails to build with MariaDB 10 though. There you have to use `0.9.3.1`.

Comment: Been looking for a few minutes around this question, this is the only solution that worked for me building a docker image, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Usually that error message implies packages are missing at the host level.

based on: [error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit)

try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

More recently, shifting to pymysql worked great.