# TA-Lib Install Error

Tags: python, linux, debian

I am trying to install TA-Lib on Debian Jessie using pip. However I am encountering the following error:

```
#include "ta-lib/ta_defs.h"
                            ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

That is just a small bit of the error. I have tried as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit) mentioned installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev

sudo easy_install greenlet

sudo easy_install gevent
```

without much luck. I am using python 3.4 on a VPS if that makes a difference. Any ideas on how I can solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

first, you should download the ta-lib at link: http://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html .This is  a c lib...

```
$ untar and cd
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

[image: make and install the c lib -ta-lib]

After this, you can input : pip install ta-lib , Successfully!
[image: The result]

Comment: great , resolved my probleam

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do ./configure --prefix=$VIRTUALENV and this will create files in your virtual env's include bin and lib folders, but after subsequently running pip3 install TA-Lib the same error as before still occurs...if you figure this out please let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had several errors while installing ta-lib (on windows), I managed to install it using conda:

```
conda install -c quantopian ta-lib=0.4.9
```

Although the installation was successful, no candle patterns where recognized.
The solution was to install **python 32 bits** and then `pip install ta-lib`, after this, the candle patterns show up.
As a side note, ta-lib for windows [only have binaries built for 32-bit](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/127#issuecomment-262853060)
Make sure you follow the [Installation-Directions](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/wiki/Installation-Directions)