# Failed installing orange on ubuntu 16:10

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, orange

I am trying to install orange 2.7.8, it crashes when running the setup.py, as shown in the picture (linked)  the last lines in the stack trace.
i tried the [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit). However it doesn't work for me.
What could be the reason and what could be the solution.

```
/usr/include/c++/6/cmath:85:3: note: candidate: constexpr double std::abs(double)
   abs(double __x)
   ^~~
In file included from source/include/stat.cpp:3:0:
source/include/stat.hpp:33:15: note: candidate: double abs(double)
 inline double abs(double x)
               ^~~
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Since you are trying to build the binary, you may not have the corresponding dev packages or their correct versions. Can you not install with `pip install orange`?

Comment: i had tried, same issue

Comment: Try using `easy_install` instead of `pip` then?

Comment: same issue again, since the problem in executing setup.py after downloading the package. it has to do something with the linux packages but i dont know which

Comment: Yes, makes sense.
Related (comments on this page) - https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python2-orange/

Comment: same issue even there, i think

Comment: Btw, if you specifically don't need v2.7.8, then you should try [`pip install orange3`](http://orange.biolab.si/download/)

Comment: it won't work on python2.7, and i need to stick on python2.7 because am using SimpleCV which is directed towards python2.7

Comment: Oh okay, all the best!

Comment: What is your gcc version (gcc -v)

Comment: gcc version 6.2.0 20161005

Comment: That's what I thought. This is most likely gcc6 issue, see my answer below. Other packages fail to compile with it as well, with exactly the same error.

Comment: @Hannu your answer below?

Comment: Deleted it as it did not help the person asking the question. Basically I suggested downgrading to gcc/g++ 5 temporarily as it has helped resolve exactly the same error with another package.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/724872/downgrade-gcc-from-5-2-1-to-4-9-ubuntu-15-10 explains how to do this with update-alternatives.

Comment: I have done what you have said @Hannu. However, it seems there is a missing package in compiling or there is an error in compiling. I couldn't find any ready compiled package as it has been in windows. I don't know what to do actually.!