# error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing pygsr,pyaudio

Tags: python, linux, gcc

I am using Python 2.7.12 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried installing `pyaudio` and `pygsr` by using commands

```
sudo pip install -U pyaudio
sudo pip install -U pygsr
```

and I got the output (error) as below:

```
    Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.10.tar.gz (287kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 296kB 762kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Unc_F6/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2uTcg2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Unc_F6/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-2uTcg2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Unc_F6/pyaudio/
```

Comment: maybe check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using the following commands on ubuntu 16.04. Tested on python 3.7 and 3.5

```html
sudo apt install portaudio19-dev python-pyaudio
pip install PyAudio
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked with `sudo apt install portaudio19-dev python3-pyaudio` on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the problem by using the package manager,

```
 $ sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

Although still has no clue why easy_install fails.

Comment: what about 'pygsr' module..??

Comment: it is included in the package :)

Comment: try this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygsr if error still exist :)

Comment: while i am importing 'pygsr' it throws error like 'ImportError: No module named pygsr'