# Failed to pip install regex in Ubuntu

Tags: python, regex, ubuntu, gcc

`pip install regex` is failing on `Ubuntu 18.04` server with this error:
I already installed packages mentioned in the supposed to be duplicate question.  So this is not a duplicate.

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
'Failed building wheel for regex'

    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/rc/Env/rcasipe/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ti8hji_4/regex/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-i25nnqtk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/rc/Env/rcasipe/include/site/python3.6/regex" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ti8hji_4/regex/
```

How do you fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setup script exited with error: command 'x86\_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit)

Comment: @dm295 thelinjk dopes not answer question.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `pip3 install regex --user`