# How get rid of x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc error in module python installation

Tags: python-3.x, pip, rpy2, linux-mint

Hi guys I am trying to install rpy2 python module on linux Mint using pip3 and I am getting this error:

```
...
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -llzma
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lbz2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-t481_z1y/rpy2/setup.py'; 
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record
/tmp/pip-p7gpudid-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-
build-t481_z1y/rpy2/
```

I did everything that I could but this error remains. I have applied the possible solutions apresented here ([same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit)), but without success. Someone please can help me? Complete track error can be found here [complete error trace](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Auuci58kKjBUgQcvVa13IYrWoQIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some missing dependencies for

- xz-devel
- bzip2-devel

you can solve this by

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev xz-utils
```

Comment: Hi, Danny thanks for answering, but I am using linux Mint, that is based in Ubuntu. So how Can I install this dependencies? I think that is not possible using yum.

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for everything. From your answer I could figure out the proper line command that is:

sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev xz-utils.

But again thank you very much.

Comment: @kizus you're welcome, may I recommend to add a tag linux Mint to your question. I'll update answer accordingly.