# Failed building wheel for cchardet when installing datadotworld

Tags: python-3.x, windows, failed-installation

I got an error when installing `datadotworld` module involving cchardet. I have already installed that package but I am still getting this error. Please help me find a solution. Here is the the full error message:

```
  Building wheels for collected packages: cchardet
  Building wheel for cchardet (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-twscuztm\\cchardet\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-xemo8o53 --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cchardet
  copying src\cchardet\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cchardet
  copying src\cchardet\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cchardet
  running build_ext
  building 'cchardet._cchardet' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\cchardet
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla\extensions
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla\extensions\universalchardet
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla\extensions\universalchardet\src
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla\extensions\universalchardet\src\base
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Isrc\ext\libcharsetdetect/mozilla/extensions/universalchardet/src/base/ -Isrc\ext\libcharsetdetect/nspr-emu/ -Isrc\ext\libcharsetdetect/ -Ic:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc\cchardet\_cchardet.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\cchardet\_cchardet.obj
  _cchardet.cpp
  src\ext\libcharsetdetect/charsetdetect.h(5): warning C4068: unknown pragma
  src\ext\libcharsetdetect/charsetdetect.h(31): warning C4068: unknown pragma
  src\cchardet\_cchardet.cpp(2351): error C2197: 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *const *,Py_ssize_t)': too many arguments for call
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cchardet
  Running setup.py clean for cchardet
Failed to build cchardet
Installing collected packages: pyflakes, pycodestyle, flake8, cchardet, tabulator, jsontableschema, datapackage, configparser, datadotworld
  Found existing installation: cchardet 2.1.4
    Uninstalling cchardet-2.1.4:
      Successfully uninstalled cchardet-2.1.4
  Running setup.py install for cchardet ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-twscuztm\\cchardet\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-52dns6_y\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cchardet
    copying src\cchardet\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cchardet
    copying src\cchardet\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cchardet
    running build_ext
    building 'cchardet._cchardet' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\cchardet
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla\extensions
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla\extensions\universalchardet
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla\extensions\universalchardet\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\ext\libcharsetdetect\mozilla\extensions\universalchardet\src\base
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Isrc\ext\libcharsetdetect/mozilla/extensions/universalchardet/src/base/ -Isrc\ext\libcharsetdetect/nspr-emu/ -Isrc\ext\libcharsetdetect/ -Ic:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc\cchardet\_cchardet.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src\cchardet\_cchardet.obj
    _cchardet.cpp
    src\ext\libcharsetdetect/charsetdetect.h(5): warning C4068: unknown pragma
    src\ext\libcharsetdetect/charsetdetect.h(31): warning C4068: unknown pragma
    src\cchardet\_cchardet.cpp(2351): error C2197: 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *const *,Py_ssize_t)': too many arguments for call
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of cchardet
  Moving to c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\cchardet-2.1.4.dist-info\
   from c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\~chardet-2.1.4.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\cchardet\
   from c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\~chardet
  Moving to c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\scripts\cchardetect
   from C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-hbm61cf2\cchardetect
Command "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-twscuztm\\cchardet\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-52dns6_y\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-twscuztm\cchardet\
```

Comment: Please consider responding to the submitted question, and if it solved your issue. Mark the question answered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just spent an hour or so wrestling with this same error, so I had to come back and help you out too.  What worked for me was going to the [cchardet setup.py](https://github.com/PyYoshi/cChardet/blob/master/setup.py) file on GitHub, and checking for dependencies that I didn't have installed.  Turns out the only one I didn't have installed yet was Cython.  I ran `pip install cython`, then `pip install datadotworld[pandas]` finally worked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me, thanks...

I've been stuck on this for the past 3hrs, this is what solved the issue.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. This is what got it to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit

Answer (score 7):

I got this same error trying to run `pip install cchardet` on Python 3.11 and installing `cython` did not fix the issue. Unfortunately, it looks like [cchardet is abandoned by the original maintainer](https://github.com/PyYoshi/cChardet/issues/81#issuecomment-1320886527).

[There is a new fork](https://github.com/PyYoshi/cChardet/issues/81#issuecomment-1329693378) of the project that fixes this issue while the PyPI committee votes to transfer ownership of the original package:

```bash
pip install faust-cchardet
```

Comment: How this works when another package depends on cchardet? I'm trying to install twint and got the same error. Installing faust-ccharded didn't help.

Comment: @Ville can you say more? this pip install should install add a `cchardet` package to `site-packages` and other packages should be able to find it just fine

Comment: works after installing cython

Comment: Worked when trying to resolve cyclic import error of `llama-index` library in ubuntu 20.04 LTS, wasn't able to import `chardet`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error because I have upgraded to `python 3.9` and the code and packages were not working. I managed to fix the error by upgrading the packages and reinstalled. Among those upgrades `cchardet` was upgraded from `2.1.4` to `2.1.7` and `numpy` from `1.16.4` to `1.22.1`.

So most likely some of these two packages did not support yet `python 3.9`.

Answer (score 1):

Install dependent projects first:

```
pip3 install cython
```

Then install

```
pip3 install cchardet aiodns
```

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Installing cython also worked for me! I was trying to install pycraigslist but it wasn't working because of a problem with installing cchardet.

This method allowed me to install cchardet and ultimately pycraigslist as well.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34640827)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).