# ubuntu 16.04 python 3.7.4 pip mysqlclient error

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I want to install mysqlclient in my ubuntu server.

python version is 3.7.4.

But I can't install this package.(It installed well in 3.6.5)

This is Error message.

```
(tmp) ubuntu@orcinus:~$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/38/c5f8bac9c50f3042c8f05615f84206f77f03db79781db841898fde1bb284/mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/ubuntu/tmp/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4oxpmvqx/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4oxpmvqx/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-1lcdb63b --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4oxpmvqx/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (29 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.7m -I/home/ubuntu/tmp/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c:38:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ubuntu/tmp/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4oxpmvqx/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4oxpmvqx/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1f31t3fb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/tmp/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4oxpmvqx/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (29 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,4,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.4 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.7m -I/home/ubuntu/tmp/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:38:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ubuntu/tmp/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4oxpmvqx/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4oxpmvqx/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1f31t3fb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/tmp/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

What should I do?

I must use mysqlclient not pymysql.

Stackoverflow says add some more details.. but I don't know what should I add more.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install python version specific python-dev. In your case you need to install `python-dev` for `python3.7`

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874511/3091398)

Answer (score 0):

install this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: You could also describe how or why this is going to solve OP's question.