# Building wheel error mysqliclient pythonnet..FAIL

Tags: python, django, linux, python-2.7, debian

I'm trying to install requirement.txt file and it seems like there's some issue with build wheel of couple packages which I can't figure out.

This is the error I'm getting

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient, ndg-httpsclient, newspaper, nltk,
oauthlib, pycountry, pycryptodomex, PyDispatcher, pyjwkest, pyodbc, pyserial, python-instagram, 
python-Levenshtein, python-openid, pythonnet, PyYAML, randomcolor, redis, requests-file, simplejson, 
ssh-import-id, supervisor, Twisted, Unidecode, winpython, zope.interface, django-pure-pagination, stem
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/rehman/projects/wdpjsenv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m500R2/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m500R2/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-m7ljPY
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-m500R2/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (39 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2.7.16=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,9,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.9 -I/usr/include/mariadb -I/usr/include/mariadb/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
  In file included from _mysql.c:29:
  /usr/include/mariadb/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
   #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
    ^~~~~~~
  In file included from _mysql.c:30:
  /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h:444:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
     MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
  _mysql.c:1915:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
    if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                           ^
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
```

And after this, I am getting failed build for pythonet as well

```
Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/rehman/projects/wdpjsenv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m500R2/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m500R2/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-Z5KOnt
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-m500R2/pythonnet/
  Complete output (44 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
    Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
    Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
    Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-m500R2/pythonnet/setup.py", line 658, in <module>
      zip_safe=False,
    File "/home/rehman/projects/wdpjsenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-m500R2/pythonnet/setup.py", line 610, in run
      return bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.run(self)
    File "/home/rehman/projects/wdpjsenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-m500R2/pythonnet/setup.py", line 245, in build_extension
      self._install_packages()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-m500R2/pythonnet/setup.py", line 424, in _install_packages
      subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=use_shell)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'mono tools/nuget/nuget.exe update -self' returned non-zero exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet
```

Comment: try upgrading pip and setuptools. Or you could download the wheel directly and try installing it that way.

Comment: @kubatucka done already didnt' work, do you know if this pythonnet and mysqlclienrt is for windows platform only?

Comment: Do you have python dev? It is suggested for linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Comment: yes @kubatucka, i have python dev already and the application seems to work without installing these two packages. so maybe its not needed but i'm not sure about that