# Platypus installation error message

Tags: installation, platypus

I am trying to install Platypus and have gotten the following error message:

```
building 'htslibWrapper' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c htslibWrapper.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/htslibWrapper.o -msse2 -msse3 -funroll-loops -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fPIC
htslibWrapper.c:243:25: fatal error: htslib/bgzf.h: No such file or directory
 #include "htslib/bgzf.h"
                         ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am new to Bioinformatics and cannot seem to find a working solution online.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the bioinformatics applications don't describe thier dependencies all that well.  See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178416/pip-install-lxml-error/5178444#5178444) for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Install htslib from http://www.htslib.org/download/ and copy c headers to Platypus root folder:

```
cp -r htslib-x.x.x/htslib platypus_folder/
```

Build again

Comment: For me what worked is cp -r htslib-x.x.x/htslib platypus_folder/src/