# Reading CSV file and replacing xml tag

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I want to read a CSV file and replace the tags within the xml file with the second column of the CSV file. The tag 'name' values are in the first column.

```
A         |    B

Value1    |    ValueX
Value2    |    ValueX
Value3    |    ValueY
```

XML structure looks like.

```
<products>
   <product>
      <name>Value1</name>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>Values2</name>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>Values3</name>
   </product>
</products>
```

**Python code**

```
import csv 
import collections
import xml.etree.ElementTree
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("jolly.xml").getroot()

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)# read rows into a dictionary format
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    list = list(reader)
    columns = collections.defaultdict(list)# each value in each column is appended to a list

for (k, v) in row.items(): #go over each column name and value
    columns[k].append(v)# append the value into the appropriate list

print columns['A']
print columns['B']
for elem in tree.findall('.//name'):
    if elem.attrib['name'] == columns['A']:
        elem.attrib['name'] == columns['B']
```

How can I handle it?

Here is how the CSV file looks like:

[Reading CSV file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIXjP.png)

The output should be looks like this:

[Value1 should be replaced with ValueX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH6BA.png)

Ok here is my solution:

```
import lxml.etree as ET


arr = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]
arr2 = ["ValuX", "ValuX", "ValueY"]

with open('file.xml', 'rb+') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for i, item in enumerate(arr):
         for elem in root.findall('.//Value1'):
             print(elem);
             if elem.tag:
                 print(item)
                 print(arr2[i])

                 elem.text = elem.text.replace(item, arr2[i])



    f.seek(0)
    f.write(ET.tostring(tree, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True))
    f.truncate()
```

Well I am using an array. I can just copy the values from file into array. For huge files it needs a better code.

Comment: Have you looked up the csv and ElementTree modules in the Python documentation? What code have you written?

Comment: Great, you have some code. What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), the special purpose, declarative language designed to restructure XML files. Like most other general purpose languages including ASP, C#, Java, PHP, Perl, VB, Python maintains an XSLT 1.0 processor, specifically in its `lxml` module.

And for your purposes, you can dynamically create an XSLT string that can be used for the transformation. Only loop needed is looping through csv data:

```
import csv
import lxml.etree as ET

# READ IN CSV DATA AND APPEND TO LIST
csvdata = []
with open('file.csv'), 'r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in readCSV:
        csvdata.append(line)

# DYNAMICALLY CREATE XSLT STRING
xsltstr = '''<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
            <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
            <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

              <!-- Identity Transform -->
              <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>

        '''

for i in range(len(csvdata)):
    xsltstr = xsltstr + \
              '''<xsl:template match="name[.='{0}']">
                  <xsl:element name="{1}">
                     <xsl:apply-templates />
                  </xsl:element>
              </xsl:template>

              '''.format(*csvdata[i])

xsltstr = xsltstr + '</xsl:transform>'

# PARSE ORIGINAL FILE AND XSLT STRING
dom = ET.parse('jolly.xml')
xslt = ET.fromstring(xsltstr)

# TRANSFORM XML
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# OUTPUT FINAL XML (PRETTY PRINT)
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True,  xml_declaration=True)

xmlfile = open('final.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<products>
  <product>
    <ValueX>Value1</ValueX>
  </product>
  <product>
    <ValueY>Value2</ValueY>
  </product>
  <product>
    <ValueZ>Value3</ValueZ>
  </product>
</products>
```

Comment: Hi many thanx for your help. Iam getting following error.: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readCSVReplaceTags.py", line 2, in <module>
    import lxml.etree as ET
ImportError: No module named lxml.etree. I have installed lxml but its not working. Is there any other module which I can go same way?

Comment: You do not have lxml installed. *I have installed lxml but its not working*? Try reinstalling `pip install lxml` and you also need `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt1-dev`. See [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178416/pip-install-lxml-error)

Comment: I am using Mac OS X 10.11

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readCSVReplaceTags.py", line 11, in <module>
    for line in readCSV:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 33: invalid continuation byte

Comment: You have special characters in your csv file: accents, foreign language items, etc. Which may require encoding. Post actual data so we can see. Do note XML tags should not have a space and not begin with a number. So check Column B.

Comment: jup I have ü, ä &amp;, etc...How can I decoded within the code?

Comment: Also getting this error: File "readCSVReplaceTags.py", line 36, in <module>
    '''.format(*csvdata[i])
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: If you failed to import, csvdata will be empty. And even if you import into Python, you will run into encoding issues in XML. Specify the encoding type in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) and in `ET.tostring()`. From your posted example data, I assure you this answer works.

Comment: Nope, its not working.   File "readCSVReplaceTags.py", line 33, in <module>
    '''.format(*csvdata[i])
IndexError: tuple index out of range  If remove .format() then it works without utf-8. If I add uft-8 then I am getthing ceback (most recent call last):
  File "readCSVReplaceTags.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open('file.csv', 'r', 'utf-8') as csvfile:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: Please post a snippet of actual data. There's something about the data triggering these issues. Any character `[A-Za-z0-9]` csv data should work. I can only speculate at this point.

Comment: See first post from me! Thnx