# Python 2.7 'Pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, pip

I tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) with no luck.

Attached is my cmd prompt output. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "python -m pip install Scrapy" ?

Comment: Show us your environmental variables.

Comment: Yes (12 char min)

Comment: Don't use `setx`. I've fallen down this hole; that truncation message is real and has consequences. You may well need to reset multiple things on your PATH now.

Comment: Right click "my computer" --> properties --> advanced settings--> environment variables. Edit your _user_ `path` variable there. Separate with `;`.

Comment: @roganjosh Your method above was the solution for me. Feel free to post if you'd like credit for an answer. And thank you for your commitment to solving this problem.

Comment: I will be home shortly so I can write it properly rather than from memory on my phone. It's a shame that the existing answers to similar questions are likely to cause more problems than they solve; these should not be so prevalent on SO :/

Comment: @phd that makes no sense. How else should a user present cmd prompt?

Comment: Using text. [See an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5178416/7976758).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not suggest using `setx` and it's unfortunate that search results specifically for `pip` point to that advice e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command). The truncation message to 1024 characters is real. It's very easy for that to simply knock things out of your PATH unintentionally and you might not know what got kicked out in Python's place, if it gets added at all. It will execute and then tell you the issue *after* the PATH has been modified. You *do* need to add `pip` to your PATH, though.

Instead, edit through right clicking My Computer and selecting "properties" (this is Windows 7):

[image]

As illustrated:

1. Advanced System Settings
2. Environment Variables
3. Edit the PATH for "User variables". Each path should be separated by `;`.

You need to add the path to `pip.exe`. It's likely in the `Scripts` subfolder of the Python installation. You need to only provide the directory path, not reference the `.exe` directly.

`setx` does have its uses. In really locked-down systems, you can still use it without admin privileges; make of that what you will.

Comment: You spent two hours critiquing the other proposed solutions before posting your own. What was the point of that? I upvoted your answer by the way... not trying to get into a dispute with you involving downvotes on our other answers, as can sometimes happen. I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @alfonso giving what I believe to be the correct response and not one that trashes the OP's Python setup? And how have I spent 2 hours doing it; I commented under the post that I was on my phone and waiting to get to a laptop? What was the point of your comment?

Comment: @alfonso I didn't downvote on this question at all btw and I missed your edit since I'm back on a phone.

Comment: The time stamps indicate two hours difference. Maybe it's more than an hour and less than two, but still. If you had a solution, why not post immediately? About downvotes, sometimes people respond to my comments by passive aggressively downvoting me across the site.

Comment: I just saw your comment about being on the train... I stand corrected. I'll be on my way.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `pip` is not on your path. Try issuing the `pip` command again in the folder `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

Comment: or whatever folder is your python2.7 installed.

Comment: @mrbTT Looking at the screenshot, that is `C:\Python27`.

Comment: No, _Don't_ use `setx`

Answer (score 0):

well, I am guessing you are using Windows system. Then I'm also guessing you specified wrong path to the pip program. Check again where is your pip.exe located and add this location to the PATH instead.

Comment: Ok, that much is clear. Are you going to elaborate on _how_?

Comment: How to find your pip.exe file or what?

Answer (score 0):

The faster way is to reinstall python, and click on the box in the installer that says:

- *Add Python X.X to PATH*

[image: python installer]

Comment: that's why i said _faster_

Comment: Nothing about this is faster. I'm busy commenting on all the incorrect ways rather than giving the proper way.