# Install libxml prebuild binaries on python2.7

Tags: python, linux, precompiled-binaries

I am having problems with installing libxml with python 2.7 . I searched [various answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904752/install-libxml2-and-associated-python-bindings-windows/1904784#1904784) in [SO they told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178416/pip-install-lxml-error) to install from prebuild binaries fro here

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.2.2

But i am not able to find on that page how to install pre build binaries . can anyone please help me with this.

Also i don't have svn installed

Answer (score 1):

You can find it, and lots of up to date binaries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

[Credit to YOU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1904784/380451)

Answer (score -1):

```
easy_install lxml
```

http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html

Comment: i trid that many times and get this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178416/pip-install-lxml-error