# Installing lxml from python index

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to install lxml from they python package index as suggested in the question below, as I run into the same problem as the original author.
original question: [Install libxml2 and associated python bindings - Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904752/install-libxml2-and-associated-python-bindings-windows?lq=1)
Package index: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.1

I have python 3.4.1 installed and am on a Windows 7 machine.

I have tried downloading a couple of the Windows installers, as I'm not sure which one is right for me. They all give the error that I don't have Python ## installed. For example, when I try the "lxml-3.4.1.win32-py3.2.exe (md5)" download it says "Python version 3.2 required, which was not found on the registry."

Is there a link on there that I should be using that I just can't see right now? Or am I missing a pre-req?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your `PATH`?

Comment: There aren't any options to change where to look. I did some more research and an installer http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml worked, I think. I'm still unable to import lxml, but I think it's a separate problem.

Comment: nvm, I just had a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml had the correct link for me, which is lxml‑3.4.1.win‑amd64‑py3.4.exe

I used that installer and then, because I'm using PyCharm, also added it as an interpreter.

Comment: I can't find that exe you mentioned. Do you happen to have a direct URL? There are only .whl there now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are installing LXML for the same architecture as the version of python you have installed. E.g. Python for amd64 requires lxml for amd64.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This was actually the solution to the same issue I ran into just a couple weeks ago. I figured when I found the answer to the same question I had, I could share it as an answer. I understand that my post would have been more appropriate in the comment section, but I'm curious what kind of answer would have been appropriate as a response to this post, since it's similar to the other answer which you didn't reply to, and actual solutions don't seem to be acceptable.