# Python module installation error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to install a module named tushare, I have tried 3 methods: pip, easy_install and setup.py install, they all have the same error:

> ImportError: No module named lxml.html

pip:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install tushare
Collecting tushare
  Using cached tushare-0.6.8.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\endeav~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pkbgde\tushare\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        import tushare
      File "tushare\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from tushare.stock.trading import (get_hist_data, get_tick_data,
      File "tushare\stock\trading.py", line 13, in <module>
        import lxml.html
    ImportError: No module named lxml.html
```

easy_install:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>easy_install tushare
Searching for tushare
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/tushare/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/0a/ca/ad9eeed1c285c58d115a0dd82734e5375abf1b6e510c7c24f2f8de921c75/tushare-0.6.8.tar.gz#md5=7626d97088d93d99c1a6ece80302d617
Best match: tushare 0.6.8
Processing tushare-0.6.8.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\endeav~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-iisas7\tushare-0.6.8\setup.cfg
Running tushare-0.6.8\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\endeav~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-iisas7\tushare-0.6.8\egg-dist-tmp-dakavz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
.......
  File "c:\users\endeav~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-iisas7\tushare-0.6.8\tushare\stock\trading.py", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lxml.html
```

setup.py install

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Users\Endeavour\Desktop\tushare-0.6.8

C:\Users\Endeavour\Desktop\tushare-0.6.8>setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Endeavour\Desktop\tushare-0.6.8\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tushare
  File "C:\Users\Endeavour\Desktop\tushare-0.6.8\tushare\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tushare.stock.trading import (get_hist_data, get_tick_data,
  File "C:\Users\Endeavour\Desktop\tushare-0.6.8\tushare\stock\trading.py", line 13, in <module>
    import lxml.html
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

I have installed python 2.7 and 3.0 on Windows 10, worked on IDLE, no IDE, how can I fix it?

Then I installed lxml:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install lxml
```

error:

```
  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
```

I could not use pip to install libxml2 and libxslt.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install libxml2
Collecting libxml2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libxml2

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install libxslt
Collecting libxslt
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxslt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libxslt
```

What could I do next?

Comment: Did you get the error about libxml2 and libxslt while installing lxml or when you tried to install tushare after installing lxml?

Comment: get lxml from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), then change the file attribute from .zip to .whl. .`C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Python27\Scripts
___________________
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip.exe install C:\Users\Endeavour\Desktop\lxml-3.6.4-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\endeavour\desktop\lxml-3.6.4-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-3.6.4
`

Comment: So it worked? Accept the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing `lxml`? It seems that all the tracebacks point to not having a module called `lxml`. Try typing into your terminal prompt: `pip install lxml`. `lxml` installs perfectly for me. 
EDIT:

Looks like libxml2 is not available in pip. I found another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904752/install-libxml2-and-associated-python-bindings-windows). It seems like they are having the same problems you are. The best part is: if you follow the [prebuilt binaries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) link (which I have conveniently linked here for you), there are downloads for lxml with libxml2 and libsxlt bundled in!

Comment: Agree with this, but I'm commenting to let you know that I think your name is awesome. LOL.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi I love my username